# Does disabling download for an uploaded DJ set on SoundCloud reduce the likelihood of having the set removed by the automatic content protection?

Tags: soundcloud

Some of my sets are sometimes removed by the automatic content protection as shown below. Does disabling download for an uploaded DJ set on SoundCloud reduce the likelihood of having the set removed by the automatic content protection?

> ---------- Forwarded message ----------
>   From: SoundCloud 
>   Date: Wed, May 8, 2013 at 1:40 PM
>   Subject: Your upload "Mix 13 - Trance Paradise" / Case #7091538
>   To: [redacted]
>
> Hi Francky,
>
> Our automatic content protection system has detected that your sound
>   "Mix 13 - Trance Paradise" may contain the following copyright
>   content: "Certainty" by Julian Vincent feat. Cathy Burton, owned by
>   Ultra Records. As a result, its publication on your profile has been
>   blocked.
>
> You can dispute this report, if you believe the copyright content has
>   been mistakenly identified or if you have obtained all the necessary
>   rights, licenses and/or permissions to upload and share this material
>   on SoundCloud.
>
> Please do so by filling out our dispute webform at the following link:
>   https://soundcloud.com/settings/disputes/7067538
>
> If you would like to learn more about copyright, please visit our
>   copyright information page.
>
> Thanks,
>
> The SoundCloud Copyright Team
>
> SoundCloud    Support Manage Notifications